# How hide Status bar and show on touch as in video players?

Tags: android, statusbar

How can I hide Status bar and show on touch as in the video players in Android 4.0.3? I tried use

`setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)`, `setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)` and `setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE)`

on tablets, but it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this flag:
public static final int SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
Since: API Level 16

Although api level 16 it is works on my 4.0.4 tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the system bar on Android tablets, sorry. You can dim the system bar, but not remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare said, that's not possible on Tablets. Use

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE);
```

to make darker the system bar for full screen mode. I am using this code and it's working well. Almost the entire screen is dark, only small grey points appear where the system buttons (back, home, ...) are.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but how developers do this in the video players? For example, ES MediaPlayer.

Comment: I don't have the tablet here to have a look. Can you upload a screenshot from ES MediaPlayer? Are there not grey points at the bottom? How then can you come back or press the home button?

Comment: ES MediaPlayer has no gray points on the StatusBar. Player hide status bar when user does not touch a screen within a few seconds. If a user touching the screen then status bar will be shown.

Comment: View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN was renamed to View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE in API v14 (both map to the constant 0x1), so this suggestion isn't really any different from what the OP tried.  For @Leo: the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION completely hides the system bar, but only until the screen is touched -- thus its only good for image/video viewers.